# Question on Tensorflow Estimator practices, should Tensorflow Operations be conducted in `my_model`, or elsewhere?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am getting an error when I try to convert my model to use a Tensorflow Estimator, and it think it's due to `my_model` not having an active session in place. So should Tensorflow operations be conducted outside of my_model ?

For example, I am getting an error by the way I currently define it:

```
def my_model( features, labels, mode, params):

    train_dataset = features
    train_labels = labels

    batch_sizeE=params["batch_size"]
    embedding_sizeE=params["embedding_size"]
    num_inputsE=params["num_inputs"]
    num_sampledE=params["num_sampled"]

    print(features)
    print(labels)

    epochCount = tf.get_variable( 'epochCount', initializer= 0) #to store epoch count to total # of epochs are known
    update_epoch = tf.assign(epochCount, epochCount + 1)

    embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_sizeE], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float32) )

    softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_sizeE],
                             stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_sizeE), dtype=tf.float32 ) )

    softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size], dtype=tf.float32),  trainable=False )

    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

    embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_sizeE*num_inputs, embedding_sizeE] )

    segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(num_inputs)

    averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

    if mode == "train":

        sSML = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
            labels=train_labels, num_sampled=64, num_classes=3096637)

        loss = tf.reduce_mean( sSML )

        optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss) 

        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=optimizer)
```

The error is at the `sSML` loss function. Here is the error

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.

<tf.Variable 'softmax_weights:0' shape=(3096637, 50) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_biases:0' shape=(3096637,) dtype=float32_ref>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-955f44867ee5> in <module>()
      1 word2vecEstimator.train(
      2     input_fn=generate_batch,
----> 3     steps=10)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    352 
    353       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 354       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    355       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    356       return self

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1205       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1206     else:
-> 1207       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1208 
   1209   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1235       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1236       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1237           features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1238       global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step(g)
   1239       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1193 
   1194     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1195     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1196     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1197 

<ipython-input-47-95d390a50046> in my_model(features, labels, mode, params)
     47 
     48         sSML = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
---> 49             labels=train_labels, num_sampled=64, num_classes=3096637)
     50 
     51         loss = tf.reduce_mean( sSML )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py in sampled_softmax_loss(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name, seed)
   1347       partition_strategy=partition_strategy,
   1348       name=name,
-> 1349       seed=seed)
   1350   labels = array_ops.stop_gradient(labels, name="labels_stop_gradient")
   1351   sampled_losses = nn_ops.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py in _compute_sampled_logits(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, subtract_log_q, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name, seed)
   1029   with ops.name_scope(name, "compute_sampled_logits",
   1030                       weights + [biases, inputs, labels]):
-> 1031     if labels.dtype != dtypes.int64:
   1032       labels = math_ops.cast(labels, dtypes.int64)
   1033     labels_flat = array_ops.reshape(labels, [-1])

TypeError: data type not understood
```

I was wondering what the error was so I tried to print out my inputs to the samples softmax and I got this error

```
`ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`
```

So it seems that there is no active graph being run?

Here's a link to my full code

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LH343QcKknMeUByjqifZPp2Hepfypz-L

Here is a link to the original question this is based on.

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` is used with interactive Session. If you use, `eval()`, you need to create a Session. However in Estimator, `tf. Estimator` will create session underneath for you, and it is not interpretive. Even Eager mode is also not supported.

```
print(softmax_weights.eval() )
print(softmax_biases.eval()  )
print(embeddings.eval()  )
print(averaged_embeds.eval()  )
```

Removing these lines would help.

Comment: " tf. Estimator will create session underneath for you".  I have something mixed up. I thought the tf.Estimator session could execute the eval(). What's the difference between an Estimator session and a regular one?

Comment: The purpose of Estimator is not to create `Session()` by hand. Estimator won't create `tf.InteractiveSession()` which is the type of session you needed to run `eval()`

Comment: If I have answered your question, please accept it.

Comment: My question is: should Tensorflow operations should be conducted outside `my_model`, since I am getting an error at this line `sSML = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights,. . . . `. I used only `.eval()` in an attempt to debug my issue. An answer to my question should state if certain Tensorflow operation and functions should only be executed outside of `my_model`, in relation to why `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss` does not work with tf.estimator, but works for a regular tensorflow session.